# Send value from NSTextField to constantly running NSTask

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask

There have been a couple of `NSTask` related questions, but after paging through them I still have no idea what to do.

I'm writing a frontend for a java server in Cocoa, launched by `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui` (I've left out the `nogui` arg in my current code so as not to fill up my computer with unnecessary orphaned instances of server).

My current code correctly runs the .jar file; now I need a way to capture (and parse) output and send input to the process.

```
server = [[NSTask alloc] init];
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-Xms1024M",
                    @"-Xmx1024M",
                    @"-jar",
                    @"server.jar",
                    nil];

[server setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/java"];
[server setCurrentDirectoryPath:@"MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/"];
[server setArguments:args];
[server setStandardOutput:pipe];
[server setStandardInput:pipe];
[server launch];
```

I've read up on `NSPipe` and `NSTask` and everything, but I can't seem an answer geared towards my problem:

- Live, parsed (RegEx?) output to `NSTextView` or `NSTableView`.
- Input from `NSTextField`

EDIT: **Or should I use `launchd`? How would I do that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make two pipes: one for the task's standard input, and another for the task's standard output.  What you're doing right now connects the task's output to its own input.

Something like this:

```
@interface ServerController : NSObject
@property (strong) NSFileHandle *standardInput;
@property (strong) NSFileHandle *standardOutput;
@end

@implementation ServerController

...

- (void)launchServer {
    NSPipe *standardInputPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    self.standardInput = standardInputPipe.fileHandleForWriting;
    NSPipe *standardOutputPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    self.standardOutput = standardOutputPipe.fileHandleForReading;
    ...
    server.standardInput = standardInputPipe;
    server.standardOutput = standardOutputPipe;
    [server launch];
}

...
```

Now you can write to the server by sending the `writeData:` message to the `standardInput` property of the `ServerController` instance.  To read from the server, you'll want to use either `readInBackgroundAndNotify` or `readabilityHandler` on the `standardOutput` property.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks so much. Now I just have to get output to go into an array...